# Can one model class have a specific relation with another set of model classes django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my models:

```
class company(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="Company_Owner",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)

class group(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    group_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True,error_messages={'unique':"This Group Name has already been registered"})
    Company = models.ForeignKey(company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Company_group')

class ledger1(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Company = models.ForeignKey(company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Companys')
    Creation_Date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
```

So these are my models I have created for my accounting application...
The company model is connected to group and ledger through foreign key...
I want to provide different group and ledgers for different companies which the user have Created...

Its just like what we do in django for all users,we need to do something like this for users:

```
 filter(User=request.user)
```

Similarly,Can I make something like this for my companies?
I mean one company will have different set of group and ledger..

Is it possible in django?
If it is Can anyone help me out to solve this...

Thank you in advance

Comment: From your model it i possible right! One company can have different groups.

Comment: Because company is in group with foreign key relation.

Comment: Can you tell me the syntax to do it...@a_k_v

Comment: Or any specific link...because I havent found it anywhere else...

Comment: If you look at the FineManual's first page, you see this -https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/#the-model-layer - with two obvious chapters to read: "making queries" and "accessing related objects".

Comment: I know that I have to use some filter to get it done...But I actually not getting it what to exactly filter...

Answer (score 2):

If I well understand what you need, it can already be done thanks to the foreign key to the company model you have on group and ledger. You just have to use in the query the "related_name" value you specified in the model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/

Example:

```
# get the companies created by the user
companies = company.objects.filter(User=request.user)

# select the company you need for example the first one
mycompany = companies.first()

# then get groups or ledgers related to it
groups = mycompany.Company_group.all()
ledgers = mycompany.Companys.all()
```

Just a suggestion: try to use always the same format when you declare classes and attributes (like always lowecase), then it become easier to read and use them.

Comment: What will be the process to exactly loop through available companies and fetch a company selected by a user and then serve the user the groups and ledgers of that specific company only?

Comment: Exactly the one explained in my answer. In the first row you filter only companies associated with the user, and if there's only one, just get the first as the example shows. Anyway, I think you should really research a bit more about django and the django orm to understand what you need and what you're doing

Comment: What if there is more than one company?

Comment: Just loop them... `for mycompany in companies: `

Comment: Do you know anything which can change the company.first() to the company which the user select

Comment: Companies are already filtered by the user in first row, if is this what you mean.

Comment: if I am doing company.first() it will only filter the groups and ledgers of the first company...What if the user select the second company which the user have created

Comment: So loop them all and take the company you need based on your needs, business logic is up to you. Here still isn't clear what is the action of "user selection" or "user creation"

Comment: For example:- its like gmail we can see the mail which we have sent and we have received because it is specific to us...So my question is that I have made a model company where one company will have different set of group and ledger provided by the user than other...So when the user will select a company from company list he will get to see the groups and ledger associated with that company